# Highlighting multiple cells in a JavaFX TableRow

Tags: javafx, tableview, tablerow

Jewelsea has provided a great example of highlighting table rows and an individual cell at [GitHub](https://gist.github.com/jewelsea/5470095).  However, I am having great difficulty with something that is closely related.

Here is a screen shot:
[image]

Using his example, when I perform the updateItem code for an individual cell in the "Will Pay Up" column, I would also like to **highlight the corresponding name** (which would be found in the same TableRow) with the same color as the cell in the will pay up column.  In the code I am actually developing I have ensured that name is always found in the first column.

Here are just a few lines from his code for updateItem (I hope this is okay):

```
// update the item and set a custom style if necessary
        if (item != null) {
          setText(item.toString());
          this.getStyleClass().add(item ? "willPayCell" : "wontPayCell");
          this.getTableRow().getStyleClass().add(item ? "willPayRow" : "wontPayRow");
        }
```

We can highlight the current cell (this.getStyleClass()) or the entire row (this.getTableRow()) but I'm unable to find a way to access another cell within the current row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the style class of the cells to something constant, and the style class of the rows depending on the item's value:

```
if (item != null) {
    setText(item.toString());
    if (! this.getStyleClass().contains("willPayCell")) {
        this.getStyleClass().add("willPayCell");
    }
    this.getTableRow().getStyleClass().removeAll("willPayRow", "wontPayRow");
    this.getTableRow().getStyleClass().add(item ? "willPayRow" : "wontPayRow");
}
```

and then you can just use the CSS to determine the colors of different cells:

```css
.table-row-cell.willPayRow .table-cell {
    -fx-background: /* color for cells other than willPayCell in willPayRow */;
}
.table-row-cell.wontPayRow .table-cell {
    -fx-background: /* color for cells other than willPayCell in wontPayRow */;
}
.table-row-cell.willPayRow .willPayCell {
    -fx-background: /* color for willPayCell in willPayRow */;
}
.table-row-cell.wontPayRow .willPayCell {
    -fx-background: /* color for willPayCell in wontPayRow */;
}
```

Comment: It took me a few minutes to follow what this does, but it works perfectly!  I really appreciate the help.

Comment: I should have pointed out, following James' answer I changed Jewelsea's code as follows:  I made the css changes to reaper.css and in the makeStringColumn method I added `if (item != null) {if (columnName.contains("Name")) { this.getStyleClass().add("willPayCell"); } setText(item); }`